# How to show bindPopUp() in Leaflet with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, leaflet

I am trying to use leaflet with angularjs. But I'm having trouble displaying array data table from "sensor" in "bindPopUp" content.
Can anyone help me how to display the data?

This is the array I'm using

```
$scope.oAllMarker = function() {
  $scope.location = [{
    "loc": "Jodhpur",
    "lat": 26.28,
    "long": 73.02,
    "sensor": [{
        "v1": 11
      }, {
        "v2": 12
      }, {
        "v3": 13
      }]
   },
   {
     "loc": "Bikaner",
     "lat": 28.0229,
     "long": 73.3119,
     "sensor": [{
        "v1": 21
      }, {
        "v2": 22
      }, {
        "v3": 23
      }]
    },
    {
      "loc": "Churu",
      "lat": 28.3254,
      "long": 74.4057,
      "sensor": [{
        "v1": 31
      }, {
        "v2": 32
      }, {
        "v3": 33
      }]
    }
  ];
```

And this is the angularjs and leaflet code i am using

```
  angular.forEach($scope.location, function(item, key) {
    $scope.dataIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "{{ url('image/storm.png') }}",
      iconSize: [38, 45]
    });
    $scope.content = String('Table:Array sensor (v1,v2,v3)');
    marker = new L.marker([parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.long)], {
      icon: $scope.dataIcon
       }).addTo($scope.map).bindPopup($scope.content);
  });
}
```